# How does my android phone load lower quality versions of pictures on the web?

Tags: browser, images

Anyone else noticed this? Even when I use my tethered connection on a computer or on the phone its self, the phone loads lower quality versions of all jpegs (I think) you look at on the web.

I guess this is to save bandwidth? But how does it do it without getting the original picture first? Which would negate any benefit of course!

Comment: Are you using the default browser or Opera?  Opera uses Opera Turbo which uses an intermediate server to compress the content.  Or maybe it's just the lower colour depth on your screen that makes them look worse.  Which phone do you have?

Comment: samsung galaxy, it happens on the native android browser and firefox on my PC (when using tethered connection).  Its definately not colour depth, the jpegs have artifacts like they are compressed :)

Answer (score 7):

It could be your provider. In the netherlands, t-mobile has an option (or at least had, I don't remember seeing it lately) to scale-down images in their proxy. As all your requests can go trough their "image" proxy at a click of a button (probably something to do with your APN, most likely server side even?)...

So it might not even have anything to do with Android..

---

It might be, but I don't remember if it was in my case, the **Web 'n' Walk Accelerator**

There's some google hits on that, though most of them semi-old. On [this link](http://www.3g.co.uk/3GForum/showthread.php?t=44215) some tips on how to fix it with that webnwalk stuff, probably not what you are looking for, but also some hints on how to send an "always reload" message to the proxy. Maybe that helps. Otherwise you might need to google some on tmobile and proxy/accelerator.

Comment: interesting, I am actually using T-Mobile, in London

Comment: Found some links to this, added one :)

Comment: O2 used to do this with pictures on my old work Blackberry. When it was tethered to a laptop all the pictures had "click to view high quality version" as a hover text. When we changed providers to Vodafone it stopped happening (even though I didn't even change phone). So definitely something the network does.